# Pass argument through action to reducer with promise/thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I am using react and redux with Promise/thunk as middleware. It works great.

There is sne thing I can't figure out. The following works:

I dispatch an action from my component:

```
this.props.dispatch(addTag({ name: name, photoId: this.props.photoId}))
```

My action executes an ajax wrapped in thunk and returns a promise:

```
export function addTag(payload) {


var url = "/api/photos/".concat(payload.photoId, "/addtag?name=" ,payload.name)
  return function(dispatch) {
    var request = new Request(url, {headers: headers});
    fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "ADD_TAG", payload: response.json()})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "ADD_TAG", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

and the reducer picks it up:

```
  case 'ADD_TAG_FULFILLED': {
    newState = state
      .set('tags', action.payload.tags)
      .set('inputValue', '')
    return newState
  }
```

Now, what if I want to pass the payload, which is passed to the action, through to the reducer? (in order to get i into state and back to the component...
I can only do this, by mingling the Thunk and kind of "breaking" the promise middleware functionality....Is this the best solution?

```
export function addTag(payload) {
  var url = "/api/photos/".concat(payload.photoId, "/addtag?name=" ,payload.name)
  return function(dispatch) {
    var request = new Request(url, {headers: headers});
    fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        return (response.json())
      })
      .then((json) => {
        dispatch({type: "ADD_TAG", payload: {suggestions: json, pl: payload})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "ADD_TAG", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say you are breaking the middleware functionality?

Comment: The component in question should receive the new redux state (not to be confused with component state) as props, are you using the library 'react-redux' with the connect() function to do this?

Comment: as long as you have access to dispatch you can fire actions and pass payloads to the reducers -> in this example you pass payloads only if fetch was successful, if you want to dispatch it always, just do it in next promise after catch statement ( you can chain them however you want )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is:

```
export function tagInput(tagInput) {
  var url = '/api/photos/get_tag_list?term='.concat(tagInput);
  return function (dispatch) {
    var request = new Request(url, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' });
    fetch(request)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TAG_INPUT', payload: response.json() });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TAG_INPUT_ERROR', payload: err });
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'TAG_INPUT_VALUE', payload: tagInput });
      });
  };
}
```